# Intent to a Facebook page. Android. Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

My textview does not Intent properly to the facebook page.

1st image should be the result but the 2nd image shows instead of the 1st image. As you can see in 2nd image, there are no Like or Follow buttons

```
public String getFacebookPageURL() {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        int versionCode = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
        boolean isFacebookEnabled = packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).enabled;
        if (isFacebookEnabled) {
            if (versionCode >= 3002580) {

                //this line is the one being returned
                return "fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + "https://facebook.com/9gag/";
            } else {
                return "fb://page/" + "";
            }

        } else {
            return "https://facebook.com/9gag/";
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return "https://facebook.com/9gag/";
    }

}

public void tv_fbpage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String facebookPageURL = getFacebookPageURL();
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(facebookPageURL));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try just fb://page/page_id

[This is a captured image from Facebook that might help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LR7m.png)

page_id is numeric and can be found in the information menu from your page.

ex) fb://page/111122223333456

```
public String getFacebookPageURL() {
    String page_id = "111122223333456";
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        boolean isFacebookEnabled = packageManager.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).enabled;
        if (isFacebookEnabled) {
            return "fb://page/" + page_id;

        } else {
            return "https://facebook.com/9gag/";
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return "https://facebook.com/9gag/";
    }

}
```